# wordpress function.php jquery conflict?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, themes

I am making a **WordPress** theme

I am trying to figure out why all of my scripts are not working... I posted my full **functions.php** below... Can anyone see what is wrong? I suspect *jquery conflict*... If so what is the problem?

let me know if you need the url where the problem is if you cannot see the mistake below...

Thank alot!

```
<?php
function biscuits_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js', array( 'jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ekko-lightbox', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/ekko-lightbox.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'biscuits_enqueue');
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        //lightbox
        $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });

        //bs-sidebar
        $(function () {
            var $window = $(window)
            var $body = $(document.body)
            var $sideBar = $('.bs-sidebar')

            var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10

            $body.scrollspy({
              target: '.bs-sidebar',
              offset: navHeight
            })

            $('.bs-docs-container [href=#]').click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault()
            })

            // back to top
            setTimeout(function () {
                    $sideBar.affix({
                    offset: {
                        top: function () {
                            var offsetTop = $sideBar.offset().top
                            var sideBarMargin = parseInt($sideBar.children(0).css('margin-top'), 10)
                            var navOuterHeight = $('.bs-docs-nav').height()

                            return (this.top = offsetTop - navOuterHeight - sideBarMargin)
                        },
                        bottom: function () {
                            return $('.bs-footer').outerHeight(true)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }, 100)

            $window.on('load resize', function () {
                $body.scrollspy('refresh')
            })

            $window.on('load', function () {
                $('.bs-top').affix();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $sideBar.affix('checkPosition')
                }, 10);
            });

            // tooltip demo
            $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
                selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
                container: "body"
            })

            $('.tooltip-test').tooltip()
            $('.popover-test').popover()

            $('.bs-docs-navbar').tooltip({
                selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]",
                container: ".bs-docs-navbar .nav"
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

The problem may be caused by this:

[image: Additional info]

Comment: Have you taken a look at any browser console, which error your code throws?

Comment: What does error message say and why would PHP ever conflict with jQuery?

Comment: php is not the problem here.. unless you see a problem... The script maybe... Here is what the console  says http://omarhabash.com/ss.png

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking about? The wp_enqueue_script or the javascript part?

`wp_enqueue_script()` takes a fourth argument which if true, will place a script in the footer as generated by `get_footer()` or `wp_footer()`. Also, you want to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` for scripts, and not `wp_footer` like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_equeue_scripts');
```

..actually, it's the [fifth argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

## . . .

In order to use jQuery, you must load the library with a `<script>` element and specify the script location with the `src` attribute.

e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://rmko/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://rmko/wp-content/themes/MyWorkout24/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

If you did everything correctly on the Wordpress side of things, a line similar to the above should appear near the top or bottom of the final HTML document. If you can not locate "jquery.js" in the final HTML document, review the previous part of this answer. Note that "bootstrap.js" must come *after* jQuery (closer to the bottom of the final HTML).

When that is in order, you may employ the usual self-executing anonymous function paradigm to pass the "special" dollar sign to a block of JavaScript code;

```
<script>
(function($){

/*
we define a function with one "special" argument [function($){...}] and call
it immediately in another function: [()(jQuery)]. The outer function is given
the global jQuery object as an argument. That global variable is defined in 
"jquery.js". 

This works less than perfectly if -this- script is "below" (in the footer) 
everything else such as elements with HTML id attributes and CSS classes
that are commonly used as jQuery selectors. To  be on the safe side you
can do this: 
*/ 

// here, $ means jQuery. 
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('form is ready to be submitted.');
    });

});


})(jQuery)
</script>
```

## . . .

*Omar, I'm going to surmise that you are new to WP/PHP/JS and welcome you to StackOverflow. However, please read introductory documentation before posting questions here, because I for one treasure this place as somewhere to find non trivial solutions and well written suggestions for hard problems.*

*It is also a good place to learn **by reading questions**. Unfortunately I fear no one will learn anything from either your question or my answer that they could not have learned by browsing the web or even a book. I hope you understand my concern regarding pollution of SO with trivial questions.*

Comment: the javascript part is what i think is wrong... Sorry me question might not be clear as this is my first wordpress site... I wrote this by modeling a default one... I know there are problems because the dom is not reading my scripts... take a look at what the console is reading. http://omarhabash.com/ss.png